# How to remove splash screen?

Tags: xna-4.0

Right, hi guys, I recently followed a tutorial http://xnadevelopment.com/tutorials/thestateofthings/thestateofthings.shtml where I wanted to create a sort of splash screen, and it worked I managed to get a two different screens interchanging between one another (so, if I press A, it goes to TitleScreen, and if I press B, it returns back to ControllerDetectScreen)

Here's the code http://paste.org/43859

Obviously there is no actual game, but if you could show me how to get rid of the TitleScreen and ControllerDetectScreen by adding a function to remove them both out of the way (preferably the spacebar, and to start my game (The background will be 'CornFlowerBlue after the function is added and pressed.)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the same code, you could add another `bool` for whether you're in the game or not, and another if statement wherever you need it to contain the code for the game (probably `Update` and `Draw`)