# How to remove splash screen from ionic application

Tags: cordova, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

***Launch application directly without splash and white screen.***
I am working on an ionic application, I need to remove splash screen being display on application launch before loading the application.

**I don't want any splash, Need to remove complete splash screen**
Don't know how to do that.
Let me show my machine setup of the application-

```
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.2.0
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-beta.32
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-beta.18
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: Mac OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68 


******************************************************
```

I have even used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8885491/how-to-remove-splash-screen)

```
<preference name="ShowSplashScreenSpinner" value="false" />
```

but this is not working for me.

Comment: how does the linked question even have any relationship to this?  The question here is about ionic2, but the linked question is about XNA.

Comment: Try uninstalling splashScreen plugin.

Comment: you are right @Claies,

Comment: @HardikVaghani tell me how to remove splashScreen, do you mean to say, i shall remove complete plugin dir of splashScreen?

Comment: `cordova plugin remove name-of-plugin` this will do work for you. Just replace plugin name in command

Answer (score 5):

To remove/disable the splashscreen add the following preference to config.xml:

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

iOS Quirk: to disable the splashscreen on ios platform you should also add `<preference name="FadeSplashScreenDuration" value="0"/>` to config.xml.

FadeSplashScreen (boolean, defaults to true): Set to false to prevent the splash screen from fading in and out when its display state changes 
`<preference name="FadeSplashScreen" value="false"/>`

For more information refer: https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen

Answer (score 4):

try running this command

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

this worked for me

Comment: I've tried other method to disable splash screen in platform browser. None of it work. I can confirm that this work when building for browser.

Comment: I tried all others for the browser. this worked for me.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your `config.xml` file

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="none" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The spinner is the loading spinner on the splash screen and not the actual splash.
Try this

```
    <preference name="ShowSplashScreen" value="false" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="0"/>
```

You can also check more options on https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen