# Ionic app launch without splash screen & even without blank screen

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, splash-screen, dynamic-splash-screen

I am using Ionic v1.
Is there a way to remove splash screen and make the app launch instantly?
I don't even want the blank screen that appears in place of splash screen image.
App has to be launched immediately.

I've tried setting splash screen to off in config.xml.
Removed splash screen plugin, but still, I see 3 seconds of blank screen before the actual app first screen appears.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255115/how-to-remove-splash-screen-from-ionic-application

Answer (score 1):

It is a known issue with Ionic that it takes quite some time to launch the app. [This post](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/ionic-2-speed-up-boot-time/46372) has gained a lot of attention on the forums. Mike Hartington from the Ionic team way back wrote:

> "So things like boot time, overall performance are all things that are
>   being worked on between ionic2 and angular2. It's something that
>   Angular 2 is focusing a lot on now, so expect to see this improve as
>   NG2 get's closer to a final release form."

Ionic is way past Angular 2 at this point, but I think the issue still persists.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. Understood that it is not possible with only Ionic right now. I am trying to know if there is any other way to remove that blank screen with the help of a native Android/iOS layer on top of Ionic.