# how to disable by default white splash screen in ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, background-process

Even when we set the duration of splash screen as 0 ms in config.xml file and package  . json file still we are getting unwanted white splash screen at the beginning of ionic app for android platform in emulator

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove splash screen from ionic application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40255115/how-to-remove-splash-screen-from-ionic-application)

Comment: same problem tho